# How can we change the font size of namesection?

Tags: fontsize

I'm making a resume and my name is too huge on the sheet (but the URL font is small). I want to create more space for content, kindly suggest.

Comment: Welcome, please share a link to the template you are using.

Comment: With that little information it is unfortunately next to possible to suggest something that is guaranteed to work for you. There are many classes for CVs out there and they are all different. A solution very much depends on the details of your document. A short example document that reproduces the issue at hand (a so-called [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/)) is required to be able to answer this properly. Without such an example, the question can't be answered in a meaningful manner. I voted to close as unclear, but I will happily vote to re-open if an example is provided.